# Shifting Window in google Big Query dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, updates

I have 30 daily sharded tables in Big Query from Nov 1 to Nov 30, 2016. 
Each of these tables follow the naming convention of "sample_datamart_YYYYMMDD".

Each of these daily tables have a field called timestampServer.

My goal is to advance the data by 24 hours at 00:00:00 UTC every day. 
So that the data is kept current without me having to copy the tables.

Is there any way to :
1) do a calculation on the field timestampServer so that it gets updated every 24 hours?
2) and at the same time rename the table name from sample_datamart_20161130 to sample_datamart_20161201?

I've read the other posts and I think those are more on aggregations in a 30 day window. My objective is not to do any aggreagtions. I just want to move the whole dataset forward by 24 hours so that when I searched for the last 1 day, there will always be data there.

Does anyone know if Google Cloud Datasets: Update be able to perform the tasks? 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/update#try-it

Thanks very much for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> As of #2 - how to rename the table name from sample_datamart_20161130
>   to sample_datamart_20161201?

This can be achieved by copying table to new table and then deleting original table.
Zero extra cost as copy job is free of charge
Table can be copied with [Jobs: Insert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) using [copy configuration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.copy) and then table can be deleted using [Tables: Delete API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/delete)

Just wanted to note that above answer just directly answers your (second) question. But somehow I feel you can go wrong direction. If you want to describe in more details what your are trying to achieve (as oposed to how you think you will implement it) we might be able to provide better help for you. If you will go this way  - I would recommend to post it as a separate question :o)